# CHAR_LENGTH IS BYTE OR CHAR

Tags: database, oracle

I am using

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_DEFAULT,CHAR_LENGTH
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SER_TBLSERVICES%'
```

`CHAR_LENGTH` shows only length, obviously :)

With reference to Oracle, if data type is `varchar2` then we have to give size and whether provided value is in bytes or chars.

How we can get information in above query - whether `CHAR_LENGTH` is in bytes or in chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

Check the value of `CHAR_USED` column:

- `'B'` means *byte* length semantics
- `'C'` means *character* length semantics

You can consult the [documentation on `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` for Oracle 10.2 here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm).